# Execute Sub when random chart is selected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have an activeX button that creates monthly charts from data logs that change daily. When you select a chart from a particular month, I want to display the min, max, and average chart values in cells B1-B3.

I imagine this is pretty easy if you have a fixed chart such as "chart1" but the user could create any number of charts on several different sheets so I don't know in advance what charts are even available.

Is there a way to create a generic chart_Activate listener that can call a sub and send it the chart's y values when any chart is activated?

Something like

```
Sub Chart_Activate() 
    yValues = <some property obtained from this listener>
    Call findMinMaxAvg(ByVal yValues) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a common Sub to each chart's `OnAction` property - name your charts so that sub can extract the information it needs via `Application.Caller`

```
Sub ShowInfo()
    Debug.Print Application.Caller
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well for getting the min, avg, max vals from the chart but now I'm stuck with another problem. I can't activate the chart with the OnAction property set.    I thought about setting it to nothing after executing the macro but then the vals won't always be correlated with the current chart (suppose you select chart 1 and then chart 2 and then back to chart 1 -- vals are for chart 2). Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to activate the chart?  You can update your question to add your current code if that will help explain.